# how to place mobile call from PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

In the PWA, I would like to give a feature where it will show user's mobile number and after tapping on call button within PWA, actual mobile call should get triggered.

I couldn't find any reference or documentation for this. Please let me know how to achieve this action ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to link a phone number, it's really similar to linking a regular website:

```
<a href="tel:15555551235">+1 (555) 555-1234</a>
```

This works for websites in general, there is nothing special about it being in a PWA.

If you want even more information about telephone links, this article is pretty good: https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/

It's from 2016 so browser support is even better. There's a bunch of info in there about SEO and country codes as well.